# Fetch names of javascripts being used by the web page using Java Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a website where I need to find which JS file is vbeing called on which particular URL.
Is there any code to fetch names of JS files being used/called by web page.
Generally I need names of JS files listed in Developers Tool > Network > JS tab.
[Image of what I want to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37W08.png). (Sample image of Stackoverflow homepage).

I have tried with code

```
DesiredCapabilities d = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
d.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(d);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
LogEntries les = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.SERVER);
for (LogEntry le : les) {
     System.out.println(le.getMessage());
}
```

But this code gives so much details which I don't need. Any way to get only names of JS files ?

Comment: If you need to know *names of JS files* you're probably doing something wrong. It should not matter in the slightest from automation standpoint where the code is located, it only matters that it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API) via JavaScript. See my example below:

```
ArrayList<String> results = (ArrayList<String>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
"return window.performance.getEntries().filter(e=>e.initiatorType==='script').map(item=>item.name);");
results.forEach((url)->System.out.println(url));
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get size of JS file as well ?